# Lua calculating total values in a table in a certain way

Tags: lua

```
local t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I Need to calculate the total values of t, from the table, the output should be 15. This is a simplified version of a more complex problem and I need to calculate the total values in a certain way, it should look like this:

```
t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
t = {3, 3, 4, 5} -- the first index is 3, from 1+2 (adding the first and second index value in the table
t = {6, 4, 5} -- the first index is 6, from 3+3
t = {10, 5} -- the first index is 10, from 6+4 
t = {15} -- 15 = 10+5
```

the calculation should stop when there is one value left in the table. How do I code this?

so far I've tried this, no luck

```
local t = {1,2,3,4,5}
local t2 = {}
--code below runs in a loop, code above doesnt
table.insert(t2, t[1] + t[2])
table.remove(t, 1)
table.remove(t, 1)
for i,v in pairs(t) do
table.insert(t2, v)
end
table.insert(t, t2[1] + t2[2])
table.remove(t2, 1)
table.remove(t2, 1)
for i,v in pairs(t2) do
table.insert(t, v)
end

print(#t) -- total values in t just went higher than before, doesnt work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
local t = {1,2,3,4,5}
while #t>1 do
    table.insert(t,1,table.remove(t,1)+table.remove(t,1))
    print(t[1],#t)
end
```

At each step, this code shifts the array twice to the left and once to the right.

Here is a less wasteful solution, which shifts the array only once per step:

```
local t = {1,2,3,4,5}
while #t>1 do
    t[2]=t[1]+t[2]
    table.remove(t,1)
    print(t[1],#t)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? You keep popping the first value from the table and add the value onto the new first value.

```
local t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

while (#t > 1) do
    local first = t[1];
    table.remove(t, 1);
    t[1] = t[1] + first;
end
```

This code modifies the current table each time it loops and does not create a new table.

Answer (score -1):

You are creating tables above the loop. Inside the loop you only pop and add values to existing tables, but for your code to work, you need to generate new tables at each iteration.

Putting `print(table.concat(t,', '))` in-between lines of your code will help you to understand what happens. "Correct" one is as follows

```
local t = {1,2,3,4,5} 
local t2 
while #t>1 do 
    t2={} 
    table.insert(t2, t[1] + t[2]) 
    table.remove(t, 1) 
    table.remove(t, 1) 
    for i,v in pairs(t) do 
        table.insert(t2, v) 
    end 
    print('t',table.concat(t,', '))
    print('t2',table.concat(t2,', '))
    t={} 
    table.insert(t, t2[1] + t2[2]) 
    table.remove(t2, 1) 
    table.remove(t2, 1) 
    for i,v in pairs(t2) do 
        table.insert(t, v) 
    end 
    print('t',table.concat(t,', '))
    print('t2',table.concat(t2,', '))
end 
print(t[1])
```

It probably won't matter for small problem, but in general it is a bad style to do array creations and copies in the loop and results in bad performance. (Try replacing `t = {1,2,3,4,5}` with  `t={}; for i=1,1e4+1 do t[i]=i; end`). Especially if you are not using most elements in the copy most of the time. Also, the above code only works if `#t` is odd.

Try thinking of alternative ways that don't involve creation of new tables or movements of large tail of array. At least see the guide on [queues](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.4.html) which are probably more complex trick than that which is needed.